# javascript limit in <head> <script>

Tags: javascript, html, function, limit, head

I was doing my WEB programming assignment for classes today. To make it simple I keep every exercise in same HTML file. While writing my last exercise , i couldn't call the new function. I tried few test functions but nothing worked. Although when I put the script in external file , it started to work.

The way I handle forms and etc. is on purpose - it's how my teacher wants it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        button
        {
            height: 50px;
            width: 200px;
            background-color: rgb(20 , 255 , 150);
            color: white;
        }
        #lista5 button
        {
            background-color: rgb(20 , 150 , 255);
        }
        #lista4 
        {
            float: left;
            width: 200px;
            background-color: grey;
        }
        #lista5
        {
            float: left;
            width: 200px;
        }
        #lista6
        {
            color: white;
            clear: both;
            background-color: grey;
            width: 800px;
            min-height: 500px;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        #zad12
        {
            margin-left: 300px;
        }
        .form
        {
            background-color: lightgray;
            color: black;
            margin: 25px;
            padding: 20px;
        }
        .form button
        {
            height: 25px;
            width: 100px;
            color: black;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="9.js"></script>
    <script>
        function zad1 ()
        {
            var wydzial = prompt("podaj swój wydział");
            alert(" Politechnika Wrocławska , wydział : " + wydzial);
            document.write("politechnika Wrocławska <br>" , wydzial);
        }
        function zad2 ()
        {
            var liczba = prompt("podaj liczbe");
            if (liczba > 0)
            {
                document.write("<font color=green>" + liczba + "</style>");
            }
            else if (liczba == 0)
            {
                document.write(liczba);
            }
            else 
            {
                document.write("<font color=red>" + liczba + "</style>");
            }
        }
        function zad3()
        {
            var a = prompt("podaj liczbe"); parseFloat(a); 
            var b = prompt("podaj liczbe"); parseFloat(b);
            if (a > b)
            {
                document.write("<h3>" + a + "</h3>");
            }
            else if (a < b)
            {
                document.write("<h3>" + b + "</h3>");
            }
            else 
            {
                document.write("liczby są równe , liczba : " + "<h3>" + a + "</h3>");
            }
        }
        function zad4 ()
        {
            var a = prompt("podja liczbe a"); 
            a = parseFloat(a);
            var b = prompt("podaj liczbe b"); 
            b = parseFloat(b);
            var suma = suma = a + b; 
            document.write(suma);
            alert(suma);
        }
        function zad5()
        {
            var a = prompt("podja liczbe a"); 
            a = parseInt(a);
            var b = prompt("podaj liczbe b"); 
            b = parseInt(b);
            var d = a / b; // dzielna
            if (a%b == 0)
            {
                document.write(d);
            }
            else 
            {
                document.write("<h1><font color=red>\n\
                liczba nie może zostać podzielona debilu -,- </font></h1>");
            }
        }
        function zad6()
        {
            var a = 1; var b = 7;
            while (a<=7 || b>0)
            {
                if (a<8)
                {
                    document.write("<h" + a + "> wydział informatyki i zarządzania</h" + a + ">");
                    document.write("<br>");
                    a++;
                }   
                else
                {
                    document.write("<h" + b + "> wydział informatyki i zarządzania</h" + b + ">");
                    document.write("<br>" + b);
                    b--;
                }   
            }
        }
        function zad7() // 5,2
        {
            var lp = prompt("oznacz początek przedziału");
            var lk = prompt("oznacz koniec przedziału");
            var i = lp; // iterator
            if (lk < lp)
            {
                alert("błąd")
            }
            while (i<=lk)
            {
                document.write(i + " ,");
                i++;
            }
        }
        function zad8()
        {
            var lp = prompt("oznacz początek przedziału"); lp = parseInt(lp);
            var lk = prompt("oznacz koniec przedziału"); lk = parseInt(lk);
            var i = lp;  // iterator
            var suma = i;
            while (i<=lk)
            {
                document.write("suma = " + suma + "<br>");
                i++;
                suma = suma + i;
            }
        }
        //zadanie 9 w pliku 9.js
        //zad 10 tak smao
        function zad11()
        {
            var n = prompt("podaj ilość liczb");
            n = parseInt(n);
            var i = 0; //iterator
            var v = 0; //wartość - value
            var suma = 0;
            while (i != n)
            {
                v = prompt("podaj wartość");
                v = parseInt(v);
                suma = suma + v;
                i++;
                v=0;
            }
            document.write(suma);
        }
        function zad12 ()
        {
            var i = 0;
            var j = 0;
            var x = []; 
            var z = 0; //zera
            var suma = 0; suma = parseInt(suma);
            var mi = 0;
            while (i < 15)
            {
                x[i] = prompt("podaj liczbe");
                x[i] = parseInt(x[i]);
                document.write(x[i] + "<br>");
                if (x[i] > 0)
                {
                    suma = suma + x[i];
                    j++;
                }
                if (x[i] == 0)
                {
                    z++;
                }
                i++;
            }
            mi = suma / j;
            document.write("suma = " + suma + "<br>" + 
                           "średnia = " + mi + "<br>" +
                           "zera = " + z + "<br>");
        }
        function zad13()
        {
            var a;
            var b;
            a = document.getElementById('l1').value; a = parseInt(a);
            b = document.getElementById('l2').value; b = parseInt(b);
            document.getElementById('sum').value = a + b;
            return false;
        }
        function zad14()
        {
            var a; var b; var c;
            function top (a , b ,c)
            {
                var a; var b; var c;
                alert ( a + b + c );
                if (a > b && a > c)
                    return a;
                else if (b > a && b > c)
                    return b;
                else if (c > a && c > b)
                    return c;
            }
            a = document.getElementById('l3').value; a = parseInt(a);
            b = document.getElementById('l4').value; b = parseInt(b);
            c = document.getElementById('l5').value; c = parseInt(c);
            document.getElementById('top').value = top(a , b , c);
            return false;
        }
        function zad15()
        {
           var a; var b;
           a = document.getElementById('l6').value; a = parseInt(a);
           b = document.getElementById('l7').value; b = parseInt(b);
           document.getElementById('sum2').value = a + b;
           document.getElementById('subt').value = a - b;
           document.getElementById('multi').value = a * b;
           document.getElementById('div').value = a / b;
           return false;
        }    
        function zad16(t)
        {
            var t;
            var a = document.getElementById('l8').value; a = parseFloat(a);
            var b = document.getElementById('l9').value; b = parseFloat(b);
            switch (t)
            {
                case 1 :
                {
                    document.getElementById('wyn').value = a + b;
                    return false;
                }
                case 2 :
                {
                    document.getElementById('wyn').value = a - b;
                    return false;
                }
                case 3 :
                {
                    document.getElementById('wyn').value = a * b;
                    return false;
                }
                case 4 :
                {
                    document.getElementById('wyn').value = a / b;
                    return false;
                }
            }
            //nastepne zadanie jest w dołączonym pliku , jakiś dziwny
            //błąd ograniczający długość kodu...
            //THIS WON'T WORK HERE
            /* function zad17(t)
            {
                var t;
                var PLN = document.getElementById('PLN').value;
                PLN = parseFloat(PLN);
                var USD = PLN / 3.10;
                var EUR = PLN / 4.19;
                var CHR = PLN / 3.41;
                if (t === 2)
                {
                    document.getElementById('USD').value = USD;
                    document.getElementById('EUR').value = EUR;
                    document.getElementById('CHR').value = CHR;
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    document.getElementById('USD').value = null;
                    document.getElementById('EUR').value = null;
                    document.getElementById('CHR').value = null;
                    document.getElementById('PLN').value = null;
                    return false;   
                }
          }
         */


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="lista4">
            <button onclick="zad1()"> zadanie 1 </button>
            <br>
            <button onclick="zad2()"> zadanie 2 </button>
            <br>
            <button onclick="zad3()"> zadanie 3 </button>
            <br>
            <button onclick="zad4()"> zadanie 4 </button>
            <br>
            <button onclick="zad5()"> zadanie 5 </button>
        </div>
        <div id="lista5">
            <button onclick="zad6()"> zadanie 1 </button>
            <br>
            <button onclick="zad7()"> zadanie 2 </button>
            <br>
            <button onclick="zad8()"> zadanie 3 </button>
            <br>
            <button onclick="max(0)"> zadanie 4 </button>
            <br>
            <button onclick="zad10()"> zadanie 5 </button>
            <br>
            <button onclick="zad11()"> zadanie 6 </button>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="lista6">
        <button id="zad12" onclick="zad12()"> zadanie </button>  
        <div class="form">
            <form id="zad13">
                Sumowanie <br>
                Podaj Liczbe 1 : <input type="text" value="0" id="l1"><br>
                Podaj Liczbe 2 : <input type="text" value="0" id="l2"><br><br>
                <button onclick="return zad13()"> oblicz </button>
                Wynik = <input type="text" value="0" id="sum" disabled>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="form">
            <form id="zad14">
                Największa <br>
                Podaj Liczbe 1 : <input type="text" value="0" id="l3"><br>
                Podaj Liczbe 2 : <input type="text" value="0" id="l4"><br>
                Podaj Liczbe 3 : <input type="text" value="0" id="l5"><br><br>
                <button onclick="return zad14()"> oblicz </button>
                Wynik = <input type="text" value="0" id="top" disabled>                    
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="form">
            <form id="zad15">
                <div style="float: left; width: 50%">
                    Podaj Liczbe 1 : <input type="text" value="0" id="l6"><br>
                    Podaj Liczbe 2 : <input type="text" value="0" id="l7"><br><br><br>  
                    <button onclick="return zad15()"> oblicz </button>  
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div style="float: left; line-height: 130%;">
                        suma <br>
                        różnica <br>
                        iloczyn <br>
                        iloraz <br>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        =<input type="text" value="0" id="sum2" disabled> <br>
                        =<input type="text" value="0" id="subt" disabled> <br>
                        =<input type="text" value="0" id="multi" disabled> <br>
                        =<input type="text" value="0" id="div" disabled> <br>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>   
        </div>
        <div class="form">
            <form id="zad16">
                <div style="float: left; width: 50%">
                    Podaj Liczbe 1 : <input type="text" value="0" id="l8"><br>
                    Podaj Liczbe 2 : <input type="text" value="0" id="l9"><br><br>
                    wynik : <input type="text" value="0" id="wyn" disabled >
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button onclick="return zad16(1)"> sumuj </button> <br>
                    <button onclick="return zad16(2)"> odejmuj </button><br>
                    <button onclick="return zad16(3)"> Mnóż </button><br>
                    <button onclick="return zad16(4)"> dziel </button><br>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="form">
            <form id="zad17">
                <div style="float: left; width: 50%; text-align: center;">
                    <b>kwota PLN</b>  <br>
                    <input type="text" id="PLN"> 
                    <br> <br> <br>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" id="EUR" disabled> EUR
                    <input type="text" id="USD" disabled> USD
                    <input type="text" id="CHR" disabled> CHR
                    <br>    
                </div>
                <div style="clear: both; text-align: center; ">
                    <button onclick="return zad17(1)"> nowa kwota </button> 
                    <button onclick="return zad17(2)"> przelicz </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

the external 9.js file :

```
function max (max) //zad 9
{
var p1 = prompt("podaj liczbe 1");
var p2 = prompt("podaj liczbe 2");
var max;
if (p1 > p2)
{
    max = p1;
}
else
{
    max = p2;
}
alert(max);
}
function zad10()
{
var lp = prompt("oznacz początek przedziału"); lp = parseInt(lp);
var lk = prompt("oznacz koniec przedziału"); lk = parseInt(lk);
var i = lp;  // iterator
var suma = i;
while (i<=lk)
{
    document.write("suma = " + suma + "<br>");
    i++;
    suma = suma + i;
}
}
function zad17(t) / this will work
{
var t;
var PLN = document.getElementById('PLN').value;
PLN = parseFloat(PLN);
var USD = PLN / 3.10;
var EUR = PLN / 4.19;
var CHR = PLN / 3.41;
if (t === 2)
{
    document.getElementById('USD').value = USD;
    document.getElementById('EUR').value = EUR;
    document.getElementById('CHR').value = CHR;
    return false;
}
else
{
    document.getElementById('USD').value = null;
    document.getElementById('EUR').value = null;
    document.getElementById('CHR').value = null;
    document.getElementById('PLN').value = null;
    return false;   
}
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention , look at exc 17 (zad 17)

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket `}` for function `zad16`

Comment: Pro tip, make a fiddle for this next time.

Comment: @T.Woody I would prefer a `<>` stack snippet, but in this specific case it will muddle the waters since one issue is inline script and document.write

Comment: Also use `break;` instead of `return false` in the switch

Comment: Also have ONE function that takes a parameter and tests it - so  instead of zad1, zad2, zad3 have zad(this) and test passed.id or passed.attr("data-whatzad") - also why zad? Give it proper names like your max function

Comment: Also this is wrong: `function zad17(t) { var t;` - passing `t` defines it

Comment: @mplungjan I don't think his question is a duplicate of the question you linked. The question the OP was asking is "Is there a size limit to the script tag in an HTML file?" But the supporting evidence that caused the question was a simply forgetting to close a function correctly. He wasn't asking for a code critique or whether or not he should use `document.write`.

Comment: He cannot use document.write except inline while loading. It will wipe the script the first time he uses it. It is the MAIN issue after the missing } which is a deletable "typo-type" question. Since I closed the question I still wanted to give some extra information

Comment: For example this will run - not prettily but will run: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/36sg4ejv/ - and the answer to OPs question is there is no specific limit he crossed other than a missing }

Comment: I agree that there are many issues with the code, and would agree that the question could/should just be deleted since it was just a typo. I was simply arguing that the question was not a duplicate of the question you linked.

Comment: You may stop arguing , the typo in exc 16 is because of copying back and forth the comment code.

Comment: Also - no proper naming because i am on Polish university and our standards are beyond my understanding so i name them in polish.

Comment: I am not great at coding  and i am aware , but some of this stuff is what i have to do. to get a passing grade. I have rewritten the function few times and even made a test one with same result.

Comment: The var t; thing will be useful for sure tho and also thanks for your code @mrplungjan